# Is it against the TOS to use get_video_info endpoint to extract a video's stream?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-dl

Is it against YouTube's terms of service to use `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=...` to extract a video's stream and display it in a video player?

I want to do this in an app I plan to share on the play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it very much is. See the [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) document, the following sections:

- III.E.1(a), downloading *Audiovisual Content*;
- III.D.7, *Undocumented Services*;
- III.E.6, *Scraping*.